# returning only non blank array results

Tags: arrays, excel

Sorry in advance for not being able to post a screen shot yet because of my rep level, as it would make explaining what I am trying to do much easier.

I'm using excel to get external data from the web so that once I get everything set up I can just refresh the data daily. I am pulling historical close prices on stocks per months so that I can run the function =(G3-G4)/G4 to get the monthly returns for the stocks. My issue is that the data pulled includes times where a dividend was issue, resulting in a blank spot on the data where the close price would normally be and giving me the #DIV/0 error. 
The function =IF(G3=$B$1,"",IF(G4=$B$1,((G3-G5)/G5),((G3-G4)/G4))) where B1 is a zero value I entered, solves my original problem, however the blank rows are still there, which will pose a problem when I do an array on another page.

Can I get an array to only return values that are not blank and shrink the number of rows to match the total number of non blank rows. So if my original date was 45 rows, 5 of which were blank could I get an output on the top 40 rows of a different excel sheet?

Comment: Add a link to a picture and someone (maybe me) will edit it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to remove blank values with a formula that you can adapt to you layout.  With values in column **A**, in **B1** enter the *Array Formula*:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$10,SMALL((IF(LEN($A$1:$A$10),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($A$1:$A$10))))),ROW(A1)),1),"")
```

and copy down.

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

The *braces* in the formula bar will appear automatically and should not be typed.

Comment: Why the `ROW(INDIRECT(ROW))` bit?  Also, I was going to use `ISBLANK` but realized it doesn't like formulas that return `""` or `'` cells.  I deleted my answer but am curious about that usage of `INDIRECT`.